# Sencha Touch Facebook Login Native App

Tags: facebook, authentication, sencha-touch

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK to implement the facebook login authorization for my Sencha Touch app. This is perfectly working when the app is running as web app but when it is compiled as native app there is no way to specify the redirect_uri parameter simply because I don't have any uri to specify since we are in the device. 
Is there any other method for Sencha Native app to implement the facebook login authorization or am I forced to implement it on server side????
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use phonegap plugin login with facebook. Here you can find it https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: Thank you very much Sagar. The plugin is working perfectly. Just installed and recompiled the application by the Cordova build command.